# Collapse footnote in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I have the following:

> The text has a long `\footnote{` so I'd like to collapse this footnote
>   `}` to make the text more legible when editing.

I want to collapse the footnote:

> The text has a long `\footnote{collapsed}` to make the text more
>   legible when editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the long footnote in a `\def`, in advance of the paragraph, and then use it at the right time.  That way, the footnote text and the paragraph text do not co-mingle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\def\myfoot{My very long footnote, which is separately defined. \lipsum[2-4]}

And to my footnote,\footnote{\myfoot} I refer you.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It also works without `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\lipsum[2-4]`. Why did you add this?

Comment: `lipsum` is just filler text.  That's what it is for.   I added it to make a long footnote with a few keystrokes, for demonstration purposes.  It will never end up in your final document.  You are right to remove them for your actual use.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround would be to use the [`footnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote) package that "defines" a `footnote` environment, and then writing

```
\begin{footnote}
    {...}
\end{footnote}
```

Environments can be collapsed, and the contents are shown as a TeX preview if you hover the mouse over the collapsed `footnoteenv`. (I'm using TeXstudio 2.7 on Ubuntu.)

**Note**: The braces inside the environment are crucial. (The reason might be a technical one: `\begin{footnote}` translates to `\footnote` in LaTeX.)